# Android Preview showing correct but running the app is not correct

Tags: android, xml

Here is my xml. It previews correct when I am in this layout. When I go to my activity main I see only the buttons and no textViews. I appreciate any help. My content main xml code is listed first then my activity main xml is listed after.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free Throw"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free Throw"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your **content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free Throw"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="Team A"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="0"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addThreeForTeamA"
            android:text="+3 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addTwoForTeamA"
            android:text="+2 Points"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:onClick="addOneForTeamA"
            android:text="Free Throw"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` should be on the top view of your content_main.xml

Comment: awesome thanks woley! A couple questions about the code you said should be on the top view. The top as in my parent linear layout which is the top one? Does that blurb of code always need to be at the top when making any app?

Comment: This parameter I mentioned is related to the `CoordinatorLayout` you are using. If you think in the layers your views are displayed it has to be on the same hierachy level as your AppBarLayout. Have a look here (at CoordinatorLayout) http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it and I bookmarked that article you linked for help as well. I will read it when I encounter another layout problem!